# Trying to implement PhotoSwipe on mobile website, but

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, photoswipe

I'm trying to setup PhotoSwipe (http://www.photoswipe.com/) which is a photo gallery jquery plugin which is compatible with mobile devices.  But I'm having trouble implementing the plugin!  I've gone through each line I was supposed to add but the plugin's not functioning at all.  The images link fine obviously, but the plugin doesn't work the way that it should.  I think missing something but I don't know what.

I'm relatively new to jQuery and I honestly don't know how anything works, I only know how to plug things in.

I've checked the file paths and everything seems to be pointed to the right place.

Here's my code.

**in 'head' tag**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe-3.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){

            $(document).ready(function(){

                var options = {};
                $("#gallery a").photoSwipe(options);

            });


        }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

    </script>
```

**in 'body' tag**

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li><a href="img/events/01.jpg"><img src="img/events/01t.jpg" rel="external" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="img/events/02.jpg"><img src="img/events/02t.jpg" rel="external"  alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="img/events/03.jpg"><img src="img/events/03t.jpg" rel="external"  alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="img/events/04.jpg"><img src="img/events/04t.jpg" rel="external"  alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="img/events/05.jpg"><img src="img/events/05t.jpg" rel="external"  alt="" /></a></li>                    
</ul>
```

Comment: First question...do you have a link online that we can link at? I've implemented Photoswipe several times without issue. Second, have you viewed your site with Chrome developer tools, or Firebug turned on? Likely that you're missing a path, or a file is missing or something like that.

Comment: PhotoSwipe is not a jQuery plugin.  One of its core features is that is no dependencies.  In this case the only place jQuery appears to be used is in `$(document).ready` but that's not necessary to initialize PhotoSwipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. Actually the link to jQuery needs to come before the link to photoswipe.

So your script files should show like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe-3.0.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh wow..okay.  Seemingly minor detail, but it makes sense that the jquery file needs to be called prior to any plugins.  Thanks for pointing that out.  That did the trick actually.  But I have a follow up question, not sure if I should be asking that here or in a separate question, but here goes.  I assumed that implementing the steps I did would give me the gallery effect, where you have the nav buttons on the bottom, instead of just the basic "swipe" effect for touch screens.  Can you point me in the right direction to get the more fancy features implemented?